# How can i include a javascript config file to my Angular main.bundle.js

Tags: angular, typescript, config

I have seen several posts on this but none of them do exactly what I'm asking for so I have to ask again.

My desire is to have a file called "config.js" that is at the root of my project which I will set up to be ignored in my git repo.  In this file all I want to do is add a number of global configuration variables that would be accessible anywhere else in the project.

One post suggested that you put the file into the assets folder and then use the HttpClient to get it.  I tried this and it does in fact work, but the problem I have is because this is a configuration file it is critically needed at the very beginning of processing any scripts. The reason this is needed is because one of the global variables is the url of the api that I will be consuming.

Doing it this way means that I have to wait for the dom to load and then wait for the ajax action to complete before I can do anything else in the application.  This is unacceptable.

On examining the files that are downloaded in the console I see a file called main.bundle.js.  I'm not sure where all the compiled typescript files end up but I'm guessing it is here.  What I would like is for my config.js to be appended to this somehow and loaded at page load time.  does this make sense, or is there a better/recommended way of doing this?

(Note, Angular 5)

Comment: Why not work the environment.<envname>.ts files and simply deploy\serve the correct environment?

Comment: Can you point me towards some documentation for this?  I did notice the environments folder under app which contains environments.ts file.  is this what you are talking about?

Comment: You create environment files with a convention (e.g. environment.qa.json).
Then, you deploy using the `ng build --env=qa` flag.
The environment.ts file (with no environment) is the default one.
You can set any properties you want (like apiUrl) and simply import it and use it in your app:

`import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';`
`this.http.get(environment.apiUrl).......`

Comment: You can look here for a better explanation: https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Comment: Here is the reason i don't like this solution: We have 7 or 8 people working on this project.  each one has their own database with their own password their own local server setup etc...  I don't want to have 7 files such as environment.bob.ts and environment.dallas.ts which have all of our personal info in them.  Each one would have to be manually added to the gitignore file

Comment: Then you can use the default one per environment and ignore when it comes to the source control. Every developer will have his own local environment.ts file. The js code will be the same when it comes to the environment schema and the big plus is that you can easily deploy your code to other envs.

Comment: Brilliant... duh..  of course.  Please post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the environment directory for that.

You add `environment.<envName>.ts` files per enviroment.
The default `environment.ts` file should be the local file. Ignore it when it comes to source control commits.

In order to deploy, use `ng build --env=<envName>`

In order to use the environment, you simply import it.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be).

Comment: While I agree this is the proper way to handle my situation, I still wonder how to add my own javascript files into the main.bundle.js (or anywhere else that would make them available)

Comment: @DallasCaley - I usually create an assets directory as a sibling of the app directory. Under that, I add custom js files that I cannot find on npm or that are internal and I add an entry in the angular-cli.json file under apps\scripts. The ng build adds the files into the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to replace keys after build.
All your keys should be string.
1. In your environment.ts, put all the keys:

```
{
keys1:"%%mykey1%%",
keys2:"%%mykey2%%"
}
```

2. You build your app as you usually do with Angular-CLI
   Then you will find your `%%mykey1%%`in your dist/main.js.
3. Make a little script to replace `%%mykey1%%` by the key you wanted.

This way, you don't need to have 100 environment files in your git repo.

Comment: This is good, but wouldn't it only work for when you build the app?  I want a solution that works for when you build as well as when you serve the app

Comment: Yes, it would only work when build the app. At work, we implemented this 2 little scripts, one for 'dev mode' and one 'for production'. We fetch properties from a remote url and bind environment directly to one versionned build.

Comment: I gave you this solution more as an "extra solution" rather than the best for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

although a bit late..
the original question almost had it right.
yes, you put your configuration in a json file, and yes, you load it with httpClient.
you were struggling how to load it in the right time..
well, APP_INITIALIZER comes to the rescue.

you can use this token to provide a service factory that will load your config before angular actually starts rendering your components.

here is a blog post about it: https://aclottan.wordpress.com/2016/12/30/load-configuration-from-external-file/